# Putty setting for different colors of text transmitted and received

Tags: terminal, putty, colors, serial-port, serial

I'm using Putty as a terminal emulator to control some equipment.  The protocol is to send a command and receive a reply, each terminated by a CR/LF.  The format of the command and reply are nearly identical.  I'd like to show them in different colors, to make it clear which are which.

I found the colors settings, but there's nothing to distinguish transmitted character colors from received character colors.  Can putty not do this?

Comment: Can putty not do this?    ............   No.

Comment: Can you suggest a different terminal emulator that can?  I also need to see control characters and dump the contents of a file to the serial port, like a command stream.

Comment: I have a license for Netterm and if does not do different colors for send / receive either. Netterm and Putty are the only two I have.

Comment: Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for doesn't exist in terminals because the concept of "transmitted characters" vs. "received characters" doesn't exist the way you imagine them. From the terminal's point of view, there are only "received characters" that appear on the screen.

I'm certain you can come up with many examples where pressing the keyboard key `x` causes the letter `x` to appear on the screen. Perhaps along with other changes, like pushing the rest of the line to the right. And I'm certain you can come up with many examples where pressing the keyboard key `x` does *not* cause the ltter `x` to appear on the screen. Maybe something else appears. Maybe the entire screen is repainted differently, perhaps not even involving a single `x` letter. Maybe nothing changes on the screen.

Even if a single `x` appears, it's not the terminal that decides to print the letter corresponding to the keypress. It sends that keycode to a remote party (the kernel, which in turn might forward it to a local app, which in turn might forward it remotely; or might send it over a serial line etc.) without changing the display. Now, the remote party often decides to paint the letter `x`, this instruction is sent back, and the terminal *receives* an `x` letter to paint. Even if this happens, this action is not connected to the keypress and the sent `x` letter in any way.

You should modify/configure the remote equipment to emit color changing escape sequences, or a distinctive prompt, or an empty line after each command's output, or whatever other visual aid that you'd prefer. Or patch some terminal emulator to apply complicated unreliable heuristics to guess (based on timing, matching up the appearing letters against earlier keypresses etc.) whether it's "input" or "output". Or write a frontend wrapper for the communication software (e.g. telnet, netcat) that does this magic.

---

Now, to complete the picture, I have to mention that there *is* a "send/receive mode" (SRM) escape sequence that allows to turn on a mode where the terminal emulator locally echoes the pressed keys, to be accompanied with settings where the remote party doesn't echo them, however, it's a highly problematic ancient legacy probably not used by anyone today, most likely not used by your equipment either. We [removed its support from VTE](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/69) more than 3 years ago and nobody complained. This would be a mode where terminals *could* theoretically change colors, but I doubt any of them would bother implementing this.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took writing your answer. However, you've changed the scenario from what I have, to your own. Even if it's the most common scenario when others use terminal emulators, it is not the scenario I am using.  I control the software/firmware at both ends of the link. The terminal end sends a command (I don't recall the ending characters, \r or \n or both). The device sends a reply that echos the same info as the command, with a response code added, typically the data being read or written.  They are similar, so different colors are good to clearly distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, I'm still not entirely certain that my response doesn't cover your use case. Are you absolutely certain (can you somehow convince me? :)) that the command that you type (and I'm not talking about the response) _appears_ on the screen as you type it because the _terminal emulator itself_ echoes them locally (the extremely rare SRM = MONITOR behavior that someone explicitly switches to), rather than your local operating system kernel in the tty driver's cooked mode echoing back the letter for each keypress?

Comment: Oh, one more thing I forgot. You way you're using Putty, I assume on Windows. I'm only familiar with Unix's tty handling. Maybe there's no counterpart of it on Windows, and Putty itself emulates its behavior, including the cooked mode line editing. In that case, Putty could internally use this information, and therefore know which are "input" vs "output" characters. That being said, this concept does not exist on terminal emulators of Unix systems (except for an extremely rare legacy mode), so it's reasonable that a Windows software that emulates it doesn't introduce this concept either.